# Flash policy request C++

Tags: json, node.js

I am writing a socket server which has a Flash client. However, I can't get past the flash policy request.

My code:

```
 if (buf[0] == 60) {
                printf("Policy request spotted");
                const auto& policy = Server::policy();

                send(client, &policy, policy.size() + 1, 0);

                close(client);
                break;
            }

std::string Server::policy(){
    char c = 0;

    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\r\n<cross-domain-policy>\r\n<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"1-31111\" />\r\n</cross-domain-policy>" + c;
}
```

Doensn't seems to work. What do I need to do to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by using this:

```
char policy[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\r\n<cross-domain-policy>\r\n<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"1-31111\" />\r\n</cross-domain-policy>\0";

send(client, &policy,  sizeof(policy), 0);
```

in the `if (buf[0] == 60) {` statement.